# How to inject default security headers with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, http-headers

I use Spring Security 5.1.6, and reading about security headers [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/default-security-headers-2.html);

> Spring Security allows users to easily inject the default security
>   headers to assist in protecting their application. The default for
>   Spring Security is to include the following headers:
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
>   Pragma: no-cache 
>   Expires: 0 
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains 
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY 
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

but from this documentation it seems like these headers are not implicitly added, so I need to inject the default headers myself. Question is, can I do that in spring-security.xml, or must I do it in some other way?

Comment: @AK47 Seems like it doesn't, because some resources doesn't get the headers. "allows users to easily inject" sounds like one actually has to do something to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, the default headers are **not** set by default, one needs to include this in the spring-security.xml:

```
<security:headers/>
```

for whatever patterns you wish to include the default headers.
Example:

```
<security:http pattern="/certainpage.html" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" authentication-manager-ref="authManagerLink">
        <security:http-basic/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/certainpage.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:headers/>
</security:http>
```

Adding only specific security headers is done like this:

```
<security:headers>
            <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
            <security:content-type-options disabled="false" />
            <security:xss-protection enabled="true" block="true" />
</security:headers>
```

I am using `<spring.security.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.security.version>`